# How to use AutoIt for Chrome and IE using selenium?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, selenium

I have written auto IT code for saving a pdf at given location through automation.  The code is as follows

```
$sSaveAsWindow = "Enter name of file to save to…"
WinWait($sSaveAsWindow,"")
If Not WinActive($sSaveAsWindow,"") Then WinActivate($sSaveAsWindow,"")
WinWaitActive($sSaveAsWindow,"")
ControlCommand ($sSaveAsWindow, "", "ToolbarWindow322", "SendCommandID", 41063)
ControlSetText($sSaveAsWindow, "", "Edit1", "D:\document")
ControlClick($sSaveAsWindow, "", "Button1")
```

This code is saving file in Firefox and code is as follows. In this i am first pressing right mouse button and than pressing the shortcut for saving file i.e. "CTRL+k" and it saving file at given location.

```
Actions save_pdf = new Actions(driver);
        Action save_action = save_pdf.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[5]/div/div[6]/ul/li[2]/a"))).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "k")).build();
        save_action.perform();

        Thread.sleep(4000);                 

        String [] cmds = new String [1];
        cmds[0]= "D:\\Demo\\TestCases\\lib\\save_pdf.exe";
        Process pp1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);                     
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        pp1.destroy();
```

But this thing is not working in Chrome and IE.

Is there any other shortcut for pressing "Save" in IE and Chrome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, it fails to open save dialog after pressing ctrl + K in Chrome? Or it fails to execute AutoIt script?

Comment: It failed because for IE we have to use "Alt+A" and for Chrome "Shift+k"

Comment: Hm, add some check to send needed keys depending on browser. If driver is instance of ChromeDriver then send ctrl + K, if it is an instance of IEDriver then send ctrl + A